# Does OpenCV has any functionality for multiple target tracking?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tracking

I have a set of videos which contain colored droplets moving around. All of them the same colour. All the droplets in the same plane, so 2D tracking.

At the moment I am using mixture of gaussians for background substraction and droplet detection, and the results are very good regarding the image segmentation.

Next step is to track them to calculate the speed. At the moment I am simply overlapping two consecutive frames. Let's say frame "i" and "i+1". Given a droplet in frame i+1 I assign it to its nearest droplet in frame i. I have a threshold of 30 pixels, so I only consider the nearer droplet in a 30 pixels radius.

This works very well when the droplets are not moving faster than that and the scene is not clustered. But I have scenes clustered with droplets (I mean around 15-20) which move very fast, and the overlapping of frames kind of frames completely. Sometimes it simply loses a droplet (the tracking, not the segmentation) because it moved more than 30 pixels, or it assigns it to another droplet which moved nearer to the previous position.

I do wonder if OpenCV has any functionality that can help me with this case. Very good segmentation, bad tracking. I have used before (not in this project) a particle filter to use the dynamics of the object to predict where it may be.

Answer (score 0):

You can find my multiple object tracker project with sources in C++ (vs2010) here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2fW5TmAtAXM
It was implemented using  MATLAB tutorials from here: http://studentdavestutorials.weebly.com/